# Kinetic energy of electron in metals

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, statistical-mechanics, electrons, temperature

Will it be correct to relate temperature of metal with kinetic energy of electron in metal just like as we do to find kinetic energy of gas molecules if we know the temperature by using the following relation:
$$E=\frac32\ k\ T$$
where $E$ = kinetic energy,
$k$ =Botzmann constant, and
$T$ = absolute temperature?

I'm asking this because there is a problem in my textbook as follows:

> Compute the typical de Broglie wavelength of an electron in a metal at $27$ °C and compare it with the mean separation between two electrons in a metal which is given to be about $2 \times 10^{–10}$ m.
> [image]

The only way I see is as I said above, is there any problem in that procedure? (for a general case)

Comment: Ask yourself:  do electrons in a metal obey the same statistics as a dilute monatomic gas?

Comment: @garyp Probably not

Comment: @garyp What can I do other than that?

Comment: What is in the "Note" that is partially visible?   Maybe there is a hint there.

Comment: Note: Exercises 11.35 and 11.36 reveal that while the wave-packets associated with gaseous molecules under ordinary conditions are non-overlapping, the electron wave-packets in a metal strongly overlap with one another. This suggests that whereas molecules in an ordinary gas can be distinguished apart, electrons in a metal cannot be distintguished apart from one another. This indistinguishibility has many fundamental implications which you will explore in more advanced Physics courses.]

Comment: Hmm.  Not much help.  I'm trying to figure out what level of solution is being sought.  Depending on the level of the course and the quality of the book, it very well may be that the answer they want is the classical answer.  That answer is wrong, but given the vague wording of the problem, it may be what they are looking for.  The point of the problem may be to show that the "classical" result has the deB wavelength greater than the mean separation.  Have you done that calculation?

Comment: @garyp yes. So should we assume electrons in metals as gases in a container?

Comment: I think the answer by @IlyaLapan has the correct perspective.   If you haven't yet covered the words "Fermi-Dirac" and "Fermi energy", then you should just assume that the electrons in metals are like gases in a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At room temperature the electrons in metals are actually a degenerate [Fermi gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_gas) and can be treated as if near absolute zero. Quoting wikipedia:

> For metals, the electron gas's Fermi temperature is generally many thousands of kelvins, so in human applications they can be considered degenerate.

The total energy of Fermi gas at absolute zero is: $$E = \frac{3}{5}E_f$$ where $E_f$ is [Fermi energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_energy).

The Wikipedia article actualy mentions the fact that this is a good model for metals:

> The three-dimensional isotropic case is known as the Fermi sphere. Let us now consider a three-dimensional cubical box that has a side length L (see infinite square well). This turns out to be a very good approximation for describing electrons in a metal.

To find the actual temperature dependance of energy on temperature at temperatures close but not exactly equal to absolute zero you would need to use Sommerfield expansion for internal energy. If I remember correctly, that would give you a factor of $T^2$ for the first order approximation but in most cases this is unnecessary, Fermi energy gives you the right order of magnitude. For more information on where those results come from see the links, the Wikipedia articles are fairly decent.

I think that all of this is beyond the scope of this question and it wants you to use classic Boltzman statistic to demonstrate that the nature of the problem is quantum mechanical. It says "compute" but what it probably means is "demonstrate why this kind of calculation is actually wrong".

EDIT: You mentioned that in "Note" section the book says: "This indistinguishibility has many fundamental implications which you will explore in more advanced Physics courses." I imagine Fermi gas and degeneracy is what they are talking about so they definitely do not expect you to know any of it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the expression you mention you are implying a classical treatment. Use the expression you mention. You should be able to the wavelength larger than the separation implying a quantum mechanical treatment for the electrons in metals.